# Evaluating an equation involving a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

Our calculus professor suggested the following problem for those with an active interest in math.

---

For any positive integer $n$, define the family of functions $f_n : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} $ as $f_{n+1}(x) = f_1(f_n(x))$, where $f_1(x) = 3x - 4x^3$.
Solve the equation: $$f_n(x) = 0$$

---

I tried to find a closed form of $f_n$, but the calculations were tedious. I also thought Newton-Raphon's method might come of some help, but I don't know how to start.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have
$$\sin(3t)=3\sin t-4\sin^3 t,$$
and now it's nearly over.